# Hyperbola with linear segment

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm looking for a simple hyperbola-like function that has a linear like segment that can be parameterized to start at `a` and end at `b` (see attached illustration). Does anybody know a simple function that fullfils that? I've been trying  `y=1/(x+1)+1/(x*a)` so far.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pnlU.png